# Want to run OpenStack in a VM

Tags: openstack, cloud, openstack-autopilot

I am interested in openstack-autopilot. I think I understand that to be useful OpenStack would require more underlying hardware, but if my goal was understanding OpenStack could one run OpenStack in a VM on a single system? If so what would be the minimum requirements for the single system?

If this is not the correct path for learning OpenStack, what would be a low cost and open source alternative?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Adam, Landscape 15.11 is now released. It gives users an option to download the OpenStack Autopilot test drive which allows you to install and run the Ubuntu OpenStack Autopilot entirely in VMware so you will not need hardware. Grab details about the [Ubuntu OpenStack Autopilot](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/openstack/autopilot) here

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu OpenStack Autopilot requires 5 machines, but keep your eye out for an upcoming VMWare solution. If you want to explore OpenStack, and Ubuntu OpenStack in particular but don't have the hardware for a real cloud, then you should look at the [Ubuntu OpenStack Installer single install guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/clouddocs/installer/en/single-install.html). This only requires a single machine, and is a great way to learn and play with OpenStack.